# Changing an inner object property to an array in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, wikipedia-api

There was such a problem, I have been suffering for a couple of days, I am still quite a novice.

Using the GET request to the Wikipedia API, I get [this object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fI2Vd.png)

It turns out that for the pages object, the name of the property (which is also an object) is always equal to pageid (in this case "9475"). How can I get access to this object if I don’t know in advance what name it will have?

Then this object must be converted to an array so that ngFor can be used.

This object I get using the **showArticleInformation** method in **search.component.ts**

**search.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Article, ArticleInformation, ArticlesService } from '../../services/articles.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search.component.css'],
  providers: [ArticlesService]
})

export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private articlesServices: ArticlesService) { }

  searchQuery: string;

  articles: { };
  articleInformation: ArticleInformation;

  getUrl(searchQuery: string) {
    return 'https://ru.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&profile=strict&search='
      + searchQuery + '&limit=100&namespace=0&format=json&origin=*';
  }

  getUrlInformation(searchQuery: string) {
    return 'https://ru.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles='
      + searchQuery + '&prop=info&format=json&origin=*';
  }

  showArticles() {
    this.articlesServices.getArticles(this.getUrl(this.searchQuery))
      .subscribe(
        (data: Article) => this.articles = Object.values({ ...data })
      );
  }

  showArticleInformation() {
    this.articlesServices.getArticleInformation(this.getUrlInformation(this.searchQuery))
      .subscribe(
        (data: ArticleInformation) => this.articleInformation = { ...data }
      );
    console.log(this.articleInformation);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

**articles.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { retry } from 'rxjs/operators';

export interface Article {
  title: string;
  collection: string[];
  description: string[];
  links: string[];
}

export interface ArticleInformation {
  batchComplete: string;
  query: {
    pages: { }
  };
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ArticlesService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getArticles(url) {
    return this.http.get<Article>(url)
      .pipe(
        retry(3),
      );
  }

  getArticleInformation(url) {
    return this.http.get<ArticleInformation>(url)
      .pipe(
        retry(3),
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: "*Then this object must be converted to an array*". Can you post what the transformed output would look like? Like this?: `{
  batchComplete: string;
  query: {
    pages: [ {pageid, ns, length}]
  };
}`

Comment: @adiga  I think so `{ batchComplete: string; query: { pages: [ pageid, ns, length] }`
In general, I need to get from this whole object only an array consisting of 2 values: `[length, touched]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're certain that `pages` will always have one property and you need only it's `value`, you could do something like this using [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values):

```js
const data = {
  batchComplete: "",
  query: {
    pages: {
      "9745": {
        pageid: 9745,
        length: 48,
        lastrevid: 100,
        contentmodel: "wikitext",
        touched: "2019-02-01"
      }
    }
  }
}

const articleInformation = {
  ...data,
  query: {
    pages: [Object.values(data.query.pages)[0]]
  }
}

console.log(articleInformation)
```

But, you need to have a separate `interface` for `this.articleInformation` and `data` since they have different structures.

Something like this:

```
export interface ArticleInformationNew {
  batchComplete: string;
  query: {
    pages: any[]
  };
}
```