# Get request using loop

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, get, httprequest

There was such a problem.

I'm trying to make a certain number of GET requests in Wikipedia API using a cycle. 
Trying to do this with the function `getAllInfo()`

**articles.components.ts**

```
export class ArticlesComponent {
  constructor(private articlesServices: ArticlesService) { }

  @Input() allTitles: string[];

  articlesInfo: ArticleInformationNew;
  allArray: [[string, number]] = [['', 0]];

  static getUrlInformation(searchQuery: string) {
    return 'https://ru.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles='
      + searchQuery + '&prop=info&format=json&origin=*';
  }

  getAllInfo() {
    for (const title of this.allTitles) {
      this.articlesServices.getArticleInformation(ArticlesComponent.getUrlInformation(title))
        .subscribe(
          (data: ArticleInformation) => this.articlesInfo = {
            ...data,
            query: { pages: [Object.values(data.query.pages)[0]]}}
        );
        this.allArray.push([this.articlesInfo.query.pages[0].touched, this.articlesInfo.query.pages[0].length]);
    }
  }
}
```

**articles.service.ts**

```
export interface ArticleInformation {
  batchComplete: string;
  query: {
    pages: {
    }
  };
}

export interface ArticleInformationNew {
  batchComplete: string;
  query: {
    pages: any[]
  };
}

export class ArticlesService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getArticleInformation(url) {
    return this.http.get<ArticleInformation>(url);
  }
}
```

An array `this.allTitles` can consist of a number of lines. **For example**: `this.allTitles = ['Naumen', 'Naumen DMS']`

I expect that the array`this.allArray` will be two-dimensional and contain arrays that consist of rows with data for each query. **For example**:

```
this.allArray[0] = ['', 0]
this.allArray[1] = ['2019-02-01T23:27:26Z', 3687]
this.allArray[2] = ['2019-01-21T04:24:21Z', 9704]
```

But in fact, it turns out that each element of a two-dimensional array is the same. **For example**:

```
this.allArray[0] = ['', 0]
this.allArray[1] = ['2019-02-01T23:27:26Z', 3687]
this.allArray[2] = ['2019-02-01T23:27:26Z', 3687]
```

Why and how to fix it?

Comment: HTTP requests are asynchronous. You have to update the array within your subscription.

Comment: @Arcteezy Hi, it's me again. You helped me a lot yesterday :D Could you tell me exactly what to write?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
getAllInfo() {
    for (const title of this.allTitles) {
      this.articlesServices.getArticleInformation(ArticlesComponent.getUrlInformation(title))
        .subscribe(
          (data: ArticleInformation) => {
            this.articlesInfo = {
                ...data,
                query: { pages: [Object.values(data.query.pages)[0]]}
            }
            this.allArray.push([this.articlesInfo.query.pages[0].touched,this.articlesInfo.query.pages[0].length]);
          } 
        );

    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, friend! Love you, you saved me the second time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `combineLatest`: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html

First, collect observables to be combined (but without subscribing to them), then combine them with `combineLatest` and get the response as an `array` and iterate over it.

```
getAllInfo() {
    console.log(this.allTitles);

    observablesToSubscribe = [];

    for (const title of this.allTitles) {
      observablesToSubscribe.push(this.articlesServices.getArticleInformation(ArticlesComponent.getUrlInformation(title)));
    }

   combineLatest(observablesToSubscribe).subscribe((responseData: Array<ArticleInformation>) => {
       responseData.forEach((responseDatum) => {
           this.allArray.push({
              ...data,
              query: { pages: [Object.values(data.query.pages)[0]]}
           })
       });   
   });     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, I misunderstood the question, but you can get pages with particular titles, by correcting your `searchQuery` (using alternative separators for titles), and get rid of `for loop`:

```
getAllInfo() {
  console.log(this.allTitles);

 this.articlesServices.getArticleInformation(
   ArticlesComponent.getUrlInformation(this.allTitles.join('|'))
     .subscribe(
       (res => {
         // here is a result with all pages of particular titles,
         // then you can process your result...
         console.log(res);

         // this.allArray is a multidimensional array
         // [["2019-01-25T00:45:06Z",4508],
         // ["2019-01-26T07:25:08Z", 773]]
         this.allArray = Object.keys(res.query.pages)
           .reduce((acc, val, index) => {
             acc[index] = [pages[val].touched, pages[val].length];
             return acc;
           }, []);
     });
}
```

`searchQuery` for titles will be in that case `Naumen | Naumen DMS` (not, for example, just `Naumen`). | (pipe) is an alternative separator for titles.

To process the result (res.query.pages):

```js
const pages = {
  "755288": {
    "pageid": 755288,
    "ns": 0,
    "title": "Spring",
    "contentmodel": "wikitext",
    "pagelanguage": "ru",
    "pagelanguagehtmlcode": "ru",
    "pagelanguagedir": "ltr",
    "touched": "2019-01-26T07:25:08Z",
    "lastrevid": 84434967,
    "length": 773
  },
  "92586": {
    "pageid": 92586,
    "ns": 0,
    "title": "Atom",
    "contentmodel": "wikitext",
    "pagelanguage": "ru",
    "pagelanguagehtmlcode": "ru",
    "pagelanguagedir": "ltr",
    "touched": "2019-01-25T00:45:06Z",
    "lastrevid": 95248014,
    "length": 4508
  },
};
 
const arr = Object.keys(pages).reduce((acc, val, index) => {
  acc[index] = [pages[val].touched, pages[val].length];
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Yes, it works, but because of this, my [past problem appears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54500727/getting-a-specific-property-in-typescript)

Comment: @Ilya Nizovcev I've added processing of result, so you'll have multidimensional array in one request